# cannot find image error in ionic jasmin unit test

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, karma-jasmine

I have html template like this

```
<div class="kiosk-logo">
                    <img  src="assets/img/logo.png"/>
                </div>
```

Its working fine. But when i run unit test  (karma + jasmine) , I am getting following error 
**ERROR in ./src/pages/welcome/welcome.html
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/img/logo.png'**

How can solve this issue ?